# When or how would I use this.flush() in a Meteor application

Tags: meteor

I am trying to understand when I might use this.flush() in a Meteor application.

The docs state the following

> Call inside publish function. Sends all the pending set, unset, and
>   complete messages to the client.

If my publish function is something like this

```
Meteor.publish('myCollection', function(myid){
    return MyCollection.find({_id: myid});
});
```

would I use this.flush()?

What kind of case would one use this.flush() in?

Thanks
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not needed in that use case, because `Meteor.publish` automatically handles the details of how to turn Mongo cursors into the appropriate `set` and `unset` commands for each subscribed client.

If you write a custom publish that manages its own `set` and `unset`, you can use `flush` to push all pending changes down to the client.  You'll find an example of that technique here: [How does the messages-count example in Meteor docs work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565654/how-does-the-messages-count-example-in-meteor-docs-work)