# How to subscribe to two different publications for the same collection?

Tags: meteor

I have this situation:

- I have a collection named Lists -> lists of sent e-mails;
- I have a collection named Emails -> all the sent emails;
- I need to show the sent e-mails for an specific list, lets say "list_id: 1";
- And, on the same page, I need to show the total sent e-mails on that day, without filtering by list_id, but by submitted_date;

How's that possible on Meteor?

Thank you!

Comment: Why downvote? That's a good question, see my comment on the first answer. That will for sure help a lot of people.

Comment: +1, here, people just expect some samples of your attempts, some code? just to see what I have you tried. I think your question was fine, because of the details in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I've found a good workaround for my issue. Subscribing to a count:

[Meteor subscribe to a count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656567/meteor-subscribe-to-a-count)

There is an example on Meteor's documentation:

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish

Maybe this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Those requests will depend on the structure of your Lists and Emails collections.

If your Lists collection is base on _id and an array of Email _id.
Then to show e-mail for a specific list:

```
Meteor.publish('emails_for_list', function(list){
  return Emails.find({
    _id: {$in: list.emails} 
  });
});
```

As for counting the total number of emails sent on a day.

```
  return Emails.find({submitted_date: today}).count();
```

Again it all depends on how you build you collections.
Instead of having a Lists collection you can as easy put an list_number on each email object.

Comment: Ok, but how can I have both subsets on my client? I just need the e-mails count sent at that day (that can be thousands), and the e-mails for the current list. I can easily publish everything, but that'd make my application to have about 5k e-mails published just to count them. Is there a better way?