# Meteor is Slow to Access a MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**Background** - I have a collection with 7,933 documents. I'm testing on a local host with a local mongodb server running. I also get the same issue on localhost with a remote mongodb server.

**Problem** - When running a simple db.collection.find().count(), meteor returns 0 documents found at first, incrementing to 7,933 over the course of about 6 seconds.

**Console** -

```
Count at: 1402440532060 is 0
Count at: 1402440533061 is 322
Count at: 1402440534064 is 1293
Count at: 1402440535087 is 2799
Count at: 1402440536557 is 4666
Count at: 1402440537696 is 7933
Count at: 1402440538697 is 7933
Count at: 1402440539699 is 7933
Count at: 1402440540701 is 7933
Count at: 1402440541702 is 7933
```

**App Structure** -

```
/client/foo.html
/clint/foo.css
/client/foo.js
/lib/collections.js
/server/server.js
```

**Code** -

/lib/collections.js:

```
fooCollection = new Meteor.Collection('fooCollection');
```

/server/server.js:

```
Meteor.publish("fooDB", function () {
  return fooCollection.find();
});
```

/client/foo.js:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe("fooDB");
});

var counter = 0;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    var ts = Date.now();
    console.log("Count at: " + ts + " is " + fooCollection.find().count());

    counter++;
    if(counter === 10) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I've tested this with multiple collections.

Also, running db.collection.find().count() in a mongo instance always returns the correct count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the collection is being streamed from the server to the client. It won't teleport over there instantly. The client's local collection is just a cache or view of the server's publication, and is not an authoritative version of the database.

To make sure that your `collection.count()` is accurate, you'll want to make sure the subscription(s) sending data are **ready**. See the docs for http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe.

Comment: Looks like I didn't do my homework. I should probably take care of counting on the server; use a meteor call to return the count; and not publish all documents to the client.

Comment: If you don't need to send all the documents to the client, you should definitely not do the count there! You can also send the count in a publication; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14656567/586086.