# How to show the total count of items and a limit list of items on a same template

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-helper

I have two sections on my page.

The first section has a limited list of items. The Second section has a total count of items (recordsCount).

When a server adds a new item I see the list of items is updated but the total count has an old value.

```
Tracks = new Mongo.Collection('tracks')
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('tracks')

Meteor.call('records', function(err, data) {
    Session.set('_records', data)
})

Template.tracks.helpers({
    tracks: function() {
        return Tracks.find()
    },
    recordsCount: function() {
        return Session.get('_records')
    }
})
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('tracks', function() {
    return Tracks.find({}, {limit: 100})
})

Meteor.methods({
    records: function() {
        return Tracks.find({}).count()
    }
})

var CronManager = new Cron(10000)
CronManager.addJob(1, function() {
    Tracks.insert({filed1: 'test'})
})
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15130030/3557327)

Comment: Check out the [publish-counts](https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/publish-counts) package.

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu, Thanks it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to efficiently bring counts into your app, check out the [publish-counts](https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/publish-counts) package.

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(author) {
  var cursor = Tracks.find(...);
  Counts.publish(this, 'tracks-count', cursor, {nonReactive: true});
});
```

The `nonReactive` options sends the count only on demand. This can be useful if you don't really need real-time counts, since most apps can do fine with updates every few seconds. That will save a lot of CPU.

```
Template.tracks.helpers({
  tracks: function() {
    return Counts.get('posts-count')
  }
});
```

Hattip to Arunoda's excellent chapter on this from [Bulletproof Meteor, Counting Documents](https://bulletproofmeteor.com/database-modeling/counting-documents/4).

Comment: Thanks, I've wrapped my server counter code in Meteor.defer like     Meteor.defer(function() {
        Counts.publish(this, 'records-of-counter', Tracks.find())
}.bind(this)) but I thinks it is good idea to avoid publish-counts package.

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated the solution with the publish-counts package. In my case it is the very heavy package.  It was loading CPU all the time. I've replace my server side code to use a collection with count field.

Common:

```
Counter = new Mongo.Collection('count')
```

Server:
    Meteor.Publish('count', function() {
       return Counter.find()
    })

```
if(Counter.find().count() === 0) Counter.insert({count: Tracks.find().count()})
var CronManager = new Cron(10000)
CronManager.addJob(1, function() {
    Counter.update({}, {$inc: {count: 1}})
    Tracks.insert({filed1: 'test'})
})
```