# change collection before publishing

Tags: meteor

I would like to add a property to the objects that get published to the client.

My publish function looks like that

```
Meteor.publish("forms", function() {
  return Forms.find();
});
```

I would like to do something like this

```
Meteor.publish("forms", function() {
  var forms = Forms.find();
  forms.forEach(function (form) {
     form.nbForms = 12;
  }

  return forms;
});
```

What I would like is that all the documents in `forms` have a new `count` attribute which gets sent to the client.

But this obviously does not work.

thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you need this to happen on the server? Why not fetch all documents on the client and then add that property to each document?

Comment: because there might be thousands of them. The goal is to publish only one page at a time but still show the total number of existing documents. And it makes no sense to store the count because each user has a different view according to their permissions. So if I was to store the count in the database, it would update in all the sessions. Which is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it will work in your case but you might use the new transform collection function introduced with Meteor 0.5.8

When declaring your collection, add this function as the second parameter :

```
Forms = new Meteor.Collection("forms", {
     transform: function(f) {
         f.nbForms = 12;
         return f;
     }
});
```

But this will be on both server and client. I don't know if there is a way to define a transform function in a publish context.

Comment: this helps but it is not exactly what I would like.
The goal is to have a different object on the client. The issue is that I need a count for each user as the result is dependent on permission

Comment: @DrGorb And why not split it into 2 subsciptions?

Comment: that would be the next best thing to changing the result on the client

Comment: the issue with transform is that it is executed on the client as well and the data is not available on the client

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something similar to this Meteor counting example in Publish:
[How does the messages-count example in Meteor docs work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565654/how-does-the-messages-count-example-in-meteor-docs-work)

I also posted a question here that may help once it's answered. Meteor has a this.added which may work, but I'm currently uncertain how to use it. Hence the question below:
[Meteor, One to Many Relationship & add field only to client side collection in Publish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688718/meteor-how-to-add-field-to-client-side-collection-in-publish)