# Meteor is not transforming my documents before publication

Tags: meteor

For security reasons, I want to add and remove properties of documents before publishing them to the client, depending on some dynamic calculations. I follow the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) and this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511191/change-collection-before-publishing/15513331#15513331).

For example simplicity, say I try to add the following static property to every document (SERVER SIDE ONLY):

```
var Docs = new Meteor.Collection('docs', {
    transform: function (f) {
        console.log('Tagging doc: ' + f._id);
        f.myProp = 1;
        return f;
    }
});
```

For some strange reason, this does not work:

1. Only some documents trigger the transform function, not all (I can see this through the console logging)
2. On the client side, none of the documents are tagged with `myProp`

I haven't tried to put the `transform` on both the client and the server, because in my real life app I cannot do the necessary computation on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform functions on collections are intended for convenience, not security -- note that when you call `observeChanges` on a cursor, the information is not passed through the transform function (it *is* passed through the transform when you call `observe`). The default way of publishing a cursor works by calling `observeChanges` on it.

If you want to strip off fields of a cursor you're publishing, use the `fields` option to `find` on your collection.  If you want to do something more complicated, you can explicitly do whatever computation you need if your publish function calls `added`, `changed`, and `removed` itself, instead of returning a cursor.  Check out the docs for [`Meteor.publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) for details.

Comment: Is there a way to tack on and send add-on/virtual fields from the server to the client, via publications?