# Meteor server reactivity

Tags: meteor

I have an app with two collections

```
Books = new Meteor.Collection("books");
Chapters = new Meteor.Collection("chapters");
```

where the documents look pretty much like this:

```
Book = {
  _id : BookId,
  users_who_can_view_this_book : [userId, userId]
}

Chapter = {
  book : BookId
}
```

On the server I publish books and chapters like this:

```
Meteor.publish('books', function() {
  return Books.find({ users_who_can_view_this_book : { $in : [this.userId] } });
});

Meteor.publish('chapters', function() {
  var bookIds = Books.find({
    users_who_can_view_this_book : {$in : [this.userId] }
  }).map(function(book) {
    return book._id;
  });
  return chapters.find({book: {$in : bookIds}});
});
```

On the client I just subscribe like this:

```
Meteor.subscribe('books');
Meteor.subscribe('chapters')
```

So, if a user has access to a book I want the client to receive the book and its corresponding chapters. This works fine on initial load.

Now, on the *server* I want to be able to add or remove users to/from the list on the book documents and when I do that, update the client with the new chapters. As of now, the client only get the update on the books, but the chapters referring to that book is not added/removed from the client.

I understand that I need to change the way my chapters publication work. I have looked at the docs for cursor.observe and cursor.observeChange, but I really cannot grasp how to use them in this case. I have also studied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565654/how-does-the-messages-count-example-in-meteor-docs-work) but I dont get all of it. I'd be happy to explain what parts of that answer I have questions about but since it's a slightly different case I dont know if is relevant. Anyway, some guidance on this or a working example would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you insert chapters inside books like this : `Book = {
  _id : BookId,
  users_who_can_view_this_book : [userId, userId],
  chapters : [chapter1, chapter2, chapterN]
}` This is more MongoDB style, and you'll only need one collection.

Comment: The main reason is that chapters has a lot of subdocuments of its own and I found working with sub-sub-documents a bit difficult with a lot of nested code, especially since collection.aggregate is not available in mini-mongo. Maybe there is a good way around that but I havent figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally untested, no-guarantees code, but replace your Meteor.publish('chapters') function with this:

```
Meteor.publish('chapters-for-me', function() {

  var self = this;

  var handle = Books.find({users_who_can_view_this_book : {$in : [self.userId] }}).observeChanges({

    added: function(id) {
      Chapters.find({book: id}).forEach(function(chapter) {
        self.added("chapters", chapter._id, chapter);
      });
    },

    removed: function(id) {
      Chapters.find({book: id}).forEach(function(chapter) {
        self.removed("chapters", chapter._id);
      });
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });

});
```

...and then change your subscriptions to this:

```
Meteor.subscribe('books');
Meteor.subscribe('chapters-for-me');
```

... and leave your collection declarations as they are.

I just wrote this on the fly, but at the very least it should steer you in the right direction on how to use observeChanges() to solve your problem.

Again, as mquandalle stated, it would probably be better if you put your Chapters documents inside your Book documents. With your current setup, if your Chapters collection starts to get really big, your server performance is going to take a significant hit.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: I'll consider going with chapters as a subdocument of books, but as I said earlier that puts me in a position where I have sub-sub-documents to loop through and it is quite painful. I think the chapters collection will grow quite big, but there wont be many occasions of books being created/changed/removed or users being added/removed from the books. Not sure if that is of any significance though.

Comment: yeah, i understand. The performance hit is going to come when your server has to grab all the chapters for a book from the Chapters collection. And if you need to make a modification on them. One thing you could do to limit the performance penalty is retain the number of chapters in your Book document, and then use it with the "limit" option when you do your Chapters.Find(). A "significant" performance hit doesn't necessarily mean an "unacceptable" performance hit, that's really up to you