# How do I make a collection reactive based on the contents of another?

Tags: meteor

In short, I want to do:

```
Meteor.publish('items', function(){ 
  return Item.find({categoryId: Categories.find({active: true} });
});
```

The flag 'active' as part of 'Categories' changes regularly.

I also tried unsub/resub to the Items collection by leveraging reactivity on the Categories collections, and it works, unfortunately it re-triggers on ANY modification to the Categories collection, regardless if it affected the 'active' flag or not.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing solved the issue of the items not being 'deleted' locally when the category is flagged as inactive on the server. Solution (ish) is to:

Client:

```
 Categories.find({active: true}).observeChanges({
    added: function(){
      itemsHandle && itemsHandle.stop();
      itemsHandle = Meteor.subscribe("items");      
    }
  });
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('items', function(){
  var category = Categories.findOne({active: true});
  return category && Items.find({categoryId: Categories.findOne({active: true}._id);
});
```

I realize this isn't perfect (still uses client side code), but it works and its the cleanest I could think of. I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Note this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/wKSOFixkvME on the same topic didn't yield any meteor-only answer , and even that was untested. AFAIK this is not possible until Meteor releases https://trello.com/c/BGvIwkEa/48-easy-joins-in-subscriptions as part of V1.0. The meteor publish-with-relations package does come close, but IMHO the above is the closest to a 'solution' so far.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a dependency object, watch for all categories change, and trigger the dep change if the active flag was toggled. Something along these lines:

```
var activeCount = Categories.find({active: true}).count();

var activeDep = new Deps.Dependency();


Deps.autorun(function() {
    var activeCountNow = Categories.find({active: true}).count();
    if(activeCountNow !== activeCount) {
        activeCount = activeCountNow;
        activeDep.changed();
    }
});

Meteor.publish('items', function(){ 
    activeDep.depend();
    return Item.find({categoryId: Categories.find({active: true} });
});
```

Note: I'm only verifying whether the number of active categories have changes so that I don't have to keep the active list in the memory. This may or may not be appropriate depending on how your app works.

---

**Edit:** Two-sided flavor mentioned in the comments:

**Client:**

```
var activeCount = Categories.find({active: true}).count();
var activeDep = new Deps.Dependency();

Deps.autorun(function() {
    var activeCountNow = Categories.find({active: true}).count();
    if(activeCountNow !== activeCount) {
        activeCount = activeCountNow;
        activeDep.changed();
    }
});

Deps.autorun(function(){
    activeDep.depend();
    Meteor.subscribe('items', new Date().getTime());
});
```

**Server:**

```
Meteor.publish('items', function(timestamp) {
    var t = timestamp;
    return Item.find({categoryId: Categories.find({active: true} });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hubert, I tried this in various combinations and cannot get it to work. The reason is that Deps.autorun is client side, not server side. If I move it client side, the activeDep var becomes undefined on the client, and if I move that too, it becomes undefined within publish() on the server

Comment: My intention was to put all of the code on the server. Is there another reason why you want this on the client? If so, try the second flavor I've just posted.

Comment: Thanks Hubert, yes I'd love everything on the server, as none of this belongs on the client for security reasons. But deps.autorun is not a server-side function, and neither is dependency.changed() they are client-side only function as far as I know. Do you have an idea of what server-side only code would look like?

Comment: You're right! I didn't thought these may be client-only functions, there's no apparent reason for that. Yes, I've got another idea, I'll write it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Categories.find().observe({
        addedAt: function(doc) {
            trigger();
        },
        changedAt: function(doc, oldDoc) {
            if(doc.active != oldDoc.active) {
                trigger();
            }
        },
        removedAt: function(oldDoc) {
            trigger();
        }
    });
});
```

Now, the `trigger` function should cause the publish to rerun. This time it's easy when it's on the client (change subscription param). I'm not sure how to do this on the server - perhaps run `publish` again.

Comment: No dice - see self-answer around this page. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following publish to solve a similar issue.  I think it is only the one line nesting of queries that limits the reactivity.  Breaking one query out inside the publish function seems to avoid the issue.

```
//on server
Meteor.publish( "articles", function(){
  var self= this;
  var subscriptions = [];

  var observer = Feeds.find({ subscribers: self.userId }, {_id: 1}).observeChanges({
    added: function (id){
             subscriptions.push(id);                                       
    },

    removed: function (id){
                subscriptions.splice( subscriptions.indexOf(id)) , 1);
    }

  });

  self.onStop( function() {
                observer.stop();
  });

  var visibleFields = {_id: 1, title: 1, source: 1, date: 1, summary: 1, link: 1};

  return Articles.find({ feed_id: {$in: subscriptions} }, { sort: {date: -1}, limit: articlePubLimit, fields: visibleFields } );

});

//on client anywhere
Meteor.subscribe( "articles" );
```

Here is another [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721057/728291) which gets the search criteria from the client through subscribe if you decide that is acceptable.

---

Update: Since the OP struggled to get this going I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikowals/6153533) and launched a working version on [meteor.com](http://publishjoin.meteor.com/).  If you just need the publish function it is as above.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work as intended - the items are never refreshed, so when the category goes inactive they still are present on the client :(

Comment: Wonder why.  The above code works reactively with any added or removed subscriptions changing what is published to each client based on their subscriptions.  It is running at http://new-river.meteor.com.

Comment: Peculiar indeed... for some reason on my box return Articles.find(...) never gets re-run, even if i can see added, removed etc are triggered in the other collection. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Ah, yes, just tried again and the problem is actually that the Articles collections doesn't get pushed to the client - that is, I think I'd have to declare what do do with the collection Articles when an Article is added, etc... very long winded.

Comment: Also, you could just get rid of the return and manually use this.added and this.removed to change what gets published.  Here I am using limit on the returned query which made the direct path harder.

Comment: No, that code works as it is with "articles" collection published to the client same as any other cursor return from publish.