# Subscribe to a count of an existing collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need to keep track of a counter of a collection with a huge number of documents that's constantly being updated. (Think a giant list of logs). What I **don't** want to do is to have the server send me a list of 250k documents. I just want to see a counter rising.

I found a very similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565654/how-does-the-messages-count-example-in-meteor-docs-work), and I've also looked into the [.observeChanges()](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes) in the docs but once again, it seems that .observe() as well as .observeChanges() actually *return* the whole set before tracking what's been added, changed or deleted.

In the above example, the "added" function will fire once per every document returned to increment a counter.

This is unacceptable with a large set - I only want to keep track of a change in the count as I understand .count() bypasses the fetching of the entire set of documents. The former example involves counting only documents related to a room, which isn't something I want (or was able to reproduce and get working, for that matter)

I've gotta be missing something simple, I've been stumped for hours.

Would really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: MongoDb doesn't have this feature. You'll need to build the count artificially, or switch platforms. The closest you can get I believe is using a capped collection, but it returns more than a count.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with the [meteor-streams](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-streams) smart package by Arunoda. It lets you do pub/sub without needing the database, so one thing you could send over is a reactive number, for instance.

Alternatively, and this is slightly more hacky but useful if you've got a number of things you need to count or something similar, you could have a separate "Statistics" collection (name it whatever) with a document containing that count.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of how to use mongo's .count() with streams?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) about this use case. I've modified it to your particular question:

```
// server: publish the current size of a collection
Meteor.publish("nbLogs", function () {
  var self = this;
  var count = 0;
  var initializing = true;
  var handle = Messages.find({}).observeChanges({
    added: function (id) {
      count++;
      if (!initializing)
        self.changed("counts", roomId, {nbLogs: count});
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      count--;
      self.changed("counts", roomId, {nbLogs: count});
    }
    // don't care about moved or changed
  });

  // Observe only returns after the initial added callbacks have
  // run.  Now return an initial value and mark the subscription
  // as ready.
  initializing = false;
  self.added("counts", roomId, {nbLogs: count});
  self.ready();

  // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
  // Stopping a subscription automatically takes
  // care of sending the client any removed messages.
  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});

// client: declare collection to hold count object
Counts = new Meteor.Collection("counts");

// client: subscribe to the count for the current room
Meteor.subscribe("nbLogs");

// client: use the new collection
Deps.autorun(function() {
  console.log("nbLogs: " + Counts.findOne().nbLogs);
});
```

There might be some higher level ways to do this in the future.